Can't open the extracted images using pygltflib
I want to convert glb into a series of images using pygltflib module in python.
my code:
import os
import base64
from pygltflib import GLTF2

def save_image(data, image_name):
    """Save the image from binary data."""
    with open(image_name, "wb") as img_file:
        img_file.write(data)

def extract_images_from_glb(glb_file):
    """Extract images from a GLB file."""
    gltf = GLTF2().load(glb_file)

    # Ensure the output directory exists
    output_dir = "../static/show/extracted_images"
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    for i, image in enumerate(gltf.images):
        image_data = None

        # Check if the image is embedded (base64) or in an external file
        if image.uri:
            if image.uri.startswith("data:image/"):
                # Extract base64 data
                header, encoded = image.uri.split(",", 1)
                image_data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
            else:
                # If it's a file, load the image directly
                try:
                    image_data = open(image.uri, "rb").read()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to open image from file: {image.uri}. Error: {e}")
                    continue
        elif image.bufferView is not None:
            # Extract image data from buffer view
            buffer_view = gltf.bufferViews[image.bufferView]
            buffer = gltf.buffers[buffer_view.buffer]

            # Read the binary data from the GLB file
            with open(glb_file, "rb") as f:
                f.seek(buffer_view.byteOffset)  # Use byteOffset from BufferView
                image_data = f.read(buffer_view.byteLength)

        # Debug: Check the size of the extracted image data
        if image_data:
            print(f"Extracted image {i}: Size = {len(image_data)} bytes")

            # Debug: Check MIME type
            mime_type = image.mimeType
            print(f"Extracting image {i} with MIME type: {mime_type}")

            # Determine the file extension based on mimeType
            if mime_type == "image/png":
                image_name = os.path.join(output_dir, f"image_{i}.png")
            elif mime_type == "image/jpeg":
                image_name = os.path.join(output_dir, f"image_{i}.jpg")
            else:
                print(f"Unsupported image type: {mime_type}. Skipping.")
                continue
            
            save_image(image_data, image_name)
            if image_data:
                print(f"Extracted image {i}: Size = {len(image_data)} bytes")
                print(f"First 20 bytes of image data: {image_data[:20]}")
            print(f"Extracted and saved: {image_name}")
        else:
            print(f"No data found for image {i}.")

# Example usage
glb_file_path = "../static/show/Dept.glb"
extract_images_from_glb(glb_file_path)

Output:
Extracted image 0: Size = 16595 bytes
Extracting image 0 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 0: Size = 16595 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'glTF\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa8\xb5\x0b\x00\x0c\x1a\x00\x00JSON'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_0.png
Extracted image 1: Size = 10031 bytes
Extracting image 1 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 1: Size = 10031 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'lW\xcdj\xb5p\x80\xbe~\xca\x9c\x08KI\x8e\xc8\x16\xb6=J'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_1.jpg
Extracted image 2: Size = 16913 bytes
Extracting image 2 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 2: Size = 16913 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'L\xd5\xfb\xc9\xe5\x1d\xd1\xe3\x92Q\x00F\x80\x96vP\xf7\xb3\x80@'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_2.jpg
Extracted image 3: Size = 8377 bytes
Extracting image 3 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 3: Size = 8377 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'\xefFDx\xdc\xbc\x0e)\xf3K4l\n\xacb\x1cd\xb0\xeb\xc9'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_3.jpg
Extracted image 4: Size = 26468 bytes
Extracting image 4 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 4: Size = 26468 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'\xcb\xcc\xcb\x95z\x81\xa5\x94\xd1\xd0\xbbk\xc1\x18j\x90\xee\x85d\xe2'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_4.jpg
Extracted image 5: Size = 58481 bytes
Extracting image 5 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 5: Size = 58481 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'Q\xddn\x9b\xd6\x0f\xa8\x0f.\xb0t\x9d\x07E{\xa8\x00\x19\x15\xc4'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_5.jpg
Extracted image 6: Size = 10294 bytes
Extracting image 6 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 6: Size = 10294 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'\x8a\x8b\xe8]C7\x93\xc3\x7f\x16\xea\xa6\xc4Y\xb3\xd4\x04\xeb\xf6{'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_6.jpg
Extracted image 7: Size = 5979 bytes
Extracting image 7 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 7: Size = 5979 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'\x0fLQ\xd0]H\xe4\x93\x0e\x89\x8e\xad\xf9REt\x10s!\x03'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_7.jpg
Extracted image 8: Size = 13706 bytes
Extracting image 8 with MIME type: image/jpeg
Extracted image 8: Size = 13706 bytes
First 20 bytes of image data: b'{\x0c\x8c\xa9\x1c\x9f\x7f\xa5P\x96\xe2\xa9\xcb68=i\x80\x14\xdc'
Extracted and saved: ../static/show/extracted_images\image_8.jpg

But i couldn't open the images in windows OS,
I tried to upload the image her but got Not a valid file type: please upload a bmp, gif, jpeg, png, or webp file.
Both in png and in jpg the same error persists. Is the error due to code? or any other issue?
Kindly help out to extract images from glb file
